# Is there a name for systems of equations with min and max functions included?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, optimization, systems-of-equations

In a big project I'm working on, I'm running into systems of equations that look like the following: 
$$a = \min(b, c)$$
$$b = d^2 + a$$
$$c = \max(a + b, d)$$

Basically, nonlinear systems of equations with min and max functions in them.  I've found a way to translate these problems into optimization problems such as linear programs, I just haven't been able to find anyone who's dealt with these type of problems directly.  Is there a name for problems like this, or a standard way people solve them?

Comment: If this type of systems is really needed in some sort of application and your method works - why not publishing it? By the way, which problem can be described by such equations?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're expecting here. $\min$ and $\max$ are just nonlinear functions like any other. So what you have here is a system of three nonlinear equations. Now, expressions like $a\leq\min\{a,b\}$ and $c\geq\max\{a+b,d\}$ are readily linearized into multiple linear inequalities; but as equations, it seems that they are just what they are.

Comment: (Well, to be fair, they are nonsmooth, so that causes a problem for certain nonlinear solvers that rely on derivatives.)